# How can I use Live Video API from a local nodejs or any other runtime?

Tags: node.js, facebook, facebook-graph-api, video, facebook-apps

I need to check if I can use the Live Video API from my local runtime (like nodejs for example) to post live videos on my page, using a long-lived access token to my page.

Whether I generate a user or page token, with Graph Explorer App ID or my own App ID, and required permissions (publish_action for my personal profile, publish_pages and manage_pages for my page), all my calls are rejected with an error:
"(#100) No permission to perform current operation."

I thought I had to create my own App and submit it for review with required items (publish_pages, manage_pages, Live Video API) but someone from the Developper Community told me that as my app is not public-facing, I couldn't get it reviewed and I shouldn't even create an App.

I also read somewhere that my page had to be whitelisted but I didn't find how to do it.

How can I use the Live Video API from a local application?

Thanks.

Best regards,
Nicolas

Comment: Of course you need an app, if you want to do anything via the API.

Comment: I'm also working on an app that uses the live videos api and am running into lots of trouble with little to no support. Maybe we could trade war stories? alistproducer2 at gmail dot com

Answer (score 0):

Using the Graph Explorer App to generate the token will make my API calls fail because I'm not the admin or a developer of the app.
So I need my own app to use the Live Video API but I don't have to submit it for review as long as I make API calls on behalf of an admin, developer, testers.

Following this documentation: [Graph API Reference](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/page/live_videos/),  using the API, I was able to post live videos on my user ID, with a (admin) user access token. 
But on my page ID, using a (admin) page access token, I'm getting this error:
"(#100) No permission to perform current operation."